# How to mute SpeechRecognizer's beep sound without muting music from MediaPlayer

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Is it possible to mute SpeechRecognizer's beep sound without muting played music from MediaPlayer?

Here code:

```
speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);

timer =  new Timer();
timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(),500,2000);

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(); 
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.breathe);
mp.reset();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
myAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0, 0);
try {
    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
    mp.prepare();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

mp.start();


class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
public void run() {

    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            speech.stopListening();
            speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

audio focus doesn't solve the problem, music is playing and I can hear beeps

I can't mute `STREAM_MUSIC` (or whole `STREAM_SYSTEM`) because I use it for `MediaPlayer`

Mute `STREAM_ALARM` isn't working for `SpeechRecognizer`

So how to mute that beep while MediaPlayer plays music

**update**

```
boolean gotFocus = requestAudioFocusForMyApp(MainActivity.this);
        if (gotFocus) {
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.breathe);
            mp.reset();
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            myAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0, 0);
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
        }
```

anti mostly code anti mostly code anti mostly code anti mostly codeanti mostly code anti mostly code anti mostly code anti mostly codeanti mostly code anti mostly code anti mostly code anti mostly codeanti mostly code anti mostly code anti mostly code anti mostly code

Comment: Are you asking for an answer of 'yes' and 'no' or you are asking on how to do it? If you asking on how to do it, you should include your code in the post.

Comment: Read this. It says, you can have your audio focus to only one source at a time. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFocusRequest.html

Comment: @UmarZaii added

Comment: @user924, I never said no. It is one of the common problem. You have to bind music with that activity where you play the music. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**I updated my answer. This should work. Check it!**

```
boolean gotFocus = requestAudioFocusForMyApp(this); /* bind with your context. */
/* You should pass your context of your service, because you are playing music via service. this parameter represents the context of your service */
                if(gotFocus) {
                   MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.breathe);
        mp.reset();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        myAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0, 0);
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
                }


private boolean requestAudioFocusForMyApp(final Context context) {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // Request audio focus for playback
        int result = am.requestAudioFocus(null,
                // Use the music stream.
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                // Request permanent focus.
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("AudioFocus", "Audio focus received");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d("AudioFocus", "Audio focus NOT received");
            return false;
        }
    }

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFocusRequest.html
```

Comment: Yes I already use it in my other project, (I play music with MediaPlayer in the service and I request audio focus before playing) `int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,stream.
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {` so beep won't be played if I add SpeechRecognizer to that project?

Comment: @user924, you are understanding just opposite. You have to bind your activity -- from where you are playing music -- with AudioFocus. You don't care any other audio sources like GoogleMaps, Speech Recognizers, Alarm etc.

Comment: I'm playing music from service class, so there I request audio focus before playing music https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/mediasession-callbacks.html

Comment: @user924, please understand AudioManager has the power to mute/unmute your audio from your system. AudioManager is for every of your apps. When you do AudioFocus to your particular Music playing class, system plays only yours class sound while muting rest of the world. Because, focus is only for one source.

Comment: Yeah I understand this, I also have `afChangeListener` to pause my player when I get `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS` there

Comment: so such beeps should not cause `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS` is it only possible for phone calls?

Comment: @user924, you said, you are playing music from your service class. You are supposed to pass this keyword in parameter instead of MainActivity.this.   This parameter is your context. You have to pass the correct context. You are doing wrong in your code there. I updated my answer.

Comment: no, this is another sample project, in this project I have only one class (MainActivity) with speach and mediaplayer

Comment: @user924, you are saying one class with both mediaplayer and speech? AudioFocus doesn't work in these type of condition. Because every Android components has different context. You have the same context. You do AudioFocus based on the context. You change your code. It should work man.

Comment: I'm also planning to put speech recognition code (just to get result in String and do something with it) to service, because my specific function should work even if user hide activity (doesn't see app), so it could be destroyed, so are you saying that I can't put all of them (mediaplayer and speech) to the same context (service class or activity class)?

Comment: should I create two different services (two classes)? and request audio focus only for needed service?

Comment: When you do AudioFocus with a particular context, audio gets focused only with that particular context. You used the same context for both mediaplayer and speech. You should separate this. You can focus for one particular thing at a time. Context is only thing that distinguishes system that two things are different. You are doing two things in the context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149937/discussion-between-uddhav-gautam-and-user924).

Comment: yeah, I get it now, I just used audio focus thinking that I just give permission for the whole app, I didn't think that I can give permission only for specific part of my app (service or activity)

Comment: @user924, the logic is very simple. Just remember, in Android (Java) context is like a primary key that differentiates components. I am glad I helped you. Would you please accept this as an answer?

Comment: yeah of course, I only hope that speech works without audio focus (mb they checks for focus like beep is very important thing if developers of it even didn't implement method in speech's class to disable beep)

Comment: bad news, speech seems to be requests for audio focus itself and my service loses focus and pauses mediaplayer

Comment: You did just opposite. You are not supposed to request focus for speech. You are supposed to request focus for your service, where there is mediaplayer.

Comment: @user924, if you are not solved yet, you can send me whole project in infofuniversities@gmail.com. I would be happy to exactly solve your issues. Please explain a little bit.

Comment: no, I requested focus in the service class (where is my mediaplayer, before playing, so it plays only if it has focus), speech I put in activity and I didn't request any focus in activity class, I'll send you sample project the other day, it's already late in my country:)

Comment: it causes `AUDIOFOCUS LOSS_TRANSIENT` in my service every time speech beeps, screenshot of focus change listener in my service:  https://postimg.org/image/vpmi7j06x/